# adding onclick listener to button stops app from working

Tags: android, eclipse, navigation, onclick, onclicklistener

I have been trying this for a long time now. Whenever I use setonclicklistener the app never opens. Crashes before starting. Onclick method added to the button by referring to android developers just gets the app started. But it crashes after clicking on the button.

Here is my MainActivity.java:
    package com.example.tyro;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

 // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);

    // Capture button clicks
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShowMainPage.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

  }
```

This is my showmainpage class

```
       package com.example.tyro;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class ShowMainPage extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_main_page);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.show_main_page, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This is my login.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/tyro_login"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
android:paddingTop="50dp"
tools:context="com.example.tyro.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/login_intro"
    android:layout_width="104dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/login_text"
    android:layout_width="327dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Please enter your username and password "
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_user"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter your username"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_pass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter your password"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/forgot_pass"
    android:layout_width="267dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Forgot your username/password?"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:text="LOGIN"



    >
</Button>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/signup_text"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Don't have an account?Click here to sign up"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/signup_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:src="@drawable/signup_button" >
</ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the logcat:

```
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tyro/com.example.tyro.ShowMainPage}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:147)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:139)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at com.example.tyro.ShowMainPage.onCreate(ShowMainPage.java:12)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
11-07 23:30:15.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16904):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: have you declare ShowMainPage in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your login_user is EditText

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/login_user"
```

You cannot cast it to Button. In your LogCat

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

UPDATE: use

```
public class ShowMainPage extends Activity {//..
```

Comment: changed it to loginbutton..still same result

Comment: changed it to a button...first screen showed up..after clicking it crashed...1st error in logcat is sayins something like you need to use a Theme.AppCombat theme

Comment: The first error many times does not point to exact cause of error. show full logcat

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared ShowMainPage in your AndroidManifest.xml?
When your app crashes,you can find the detail reason in your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

this is EditText

```
 <EditText
 android:id="@+id/login_user"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
 android:ems="10"
 android:hint="Enter your username"
 android:inputType="textPersonName"
 android:textColor="#ffffff"
 android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />
```

us r using this

```
 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_user);
 this is button not edittext so this regian u geting error
```

check edit text to Button in xml file

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/login_user"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to change extend ActionBarActivity to Activity and it started working